# What happens when we hit Ctrl + F5

Tags: asp.net, iis

This could be a very naive question but I am curious to know.
What happens when we hit `Ctrl + F5` on a web Application project in Visual Studio? I know IIS hosts this on localhost and redirects to that page. I want to understand the unseen things behind this deployment on IIS and how different it is in relative to  typical publishing activity like creating a publish directory and adding a site to it in IIS as virtual directory and browsing it on local ma chine?

Because, most of the times no one cares to explain what happens on `Ctrl + F5` but a lot of us use it to test our websites before publishing.

Comment: Start without debugging - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/01/start-debugging-vs-start-without-debugging-vstipdebug0037.aspx

Comment: @Rudy: Thanks for the reply. It says what happens on Debug and without Debug in general but doesn't answer my question of how we can browse "published" like websites on localhost. Where this webapp is hosted etc.. I am asking `CTRL + F5` in relative to Web Applications .Hope I am clear now.

Comment: Check Output window in Visual Studio when you hit Ctrl+F5 to get details of what is happening